# Java Postgis how to convert jts to coordinates

Tags: java, postgis

I have coordinates in my postgis database with the format shape geometry :

```
"0102000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000049400000000000005440"
```

How can I convert it in coordinates (x,y) in Java ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PostGIS functions:

```
SELECT path[1] AS number,
       st_x(geom),
       st_y(geom)
FROM st_dumppoints(
        '0102000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000049400000000000005440'::geometry
     );

 number | st_x | st_y 
--------+------+------
      1 |    0 |    0
      2 |   50 |   80
(2 rows)
```

Comment: thank you very much ! @LaurenzAlbe If i wouldike to have only [0;0], [50,80] in out ?

Comment: Then change the query accordingly!